# How to get related/similar search results?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, full-text-search

What's the best way in ASP.NET MVC to get a few questions related to the current question (like on Stack Overflow) without using tags?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a database question than an ASP.NET question.

It depends on how intelligent and powerful you want the searching to be.  If you just want to search on the title, the LIKE keyword can be used to match a string.  If you're using SQL Server 2005/2008 and you want to search on entire records, you can look into [full-text searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx).